# Is storing encrypted and hashed versions of the same data less secure?

Tags: encryption, hash

I have some database columns which are encrypted. Obviously there is no way to filter these by plaintext value. As the data stored in the db is ~~salted~~ combined with the IV, there is no way to recreate the cypher text.

The value in the database is created like so:

```
db_value = base64(json([iv, cypher, mac]))
```

...so without the IV, I can't create `db_value`. And I can't find the IV without reading db_value.

I could get around this by creating another column to store a hash of the data.

Is this a bad idea? Would keeping the data in multiple formats like this make it less secure?

Comment: Your question is unclear : you say that some columns are encrypted + salted. Don't you mean they are hashed + salted instead ? If it's the case, what you want is to create another column with an unsalted hash of the same data ? Strange, or I misunderstood something :)

Comment: @niilzon I believe he means encrypted columns.  There are multiple reasons to keep encrypted blobs of information in databases including PII.  His problem now is searching those databases for the encrypted data.

Comment: @RoraZ I undertand that, but I never heard of salting encrypted data, as far as I know one can salt plaintext for hashing to prevent usage of rainbow-tables during cracking. I'm confused, but I don't know everything so I'll just watch this page ;)

Comment: Sorry if I'm describing it wrong! Basically the encryption isn't deterministic. The cypher and salt are combined into the same field in the database, meaning the only way to get the salt and re-encrypt the plaintext would be to go through each row individually, which defeats the purpose. I know that making a salt as I described would work. I'm just not sure if it is sensible.

Comment: You keep using those words... I don't think they mean what you think they mean... ;o) If the encryption wasn't deterministic, you wouldn't ever be able to decrypt anything... Perhaps give us some (pseudo) code for your algorithm instead of badly describing it?

Comment: I'd guess he's talking about a randomized IV. But that's just a guess...

Comment: @deceze : ​ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @deceze I am super pro. I know all the words :) What I mean is that if I encrypt the same plaintext, the data that ends up in the database will be different as it is a combination of the iv, encrypted value and mac. So I can't recreate the end result without decrypted each record individually.

Comment: So you're randomising the IV, which makes a lot more sense, and means you still have a *deterministic* algorithm.

Comment: I feel like we're going off on a tangent. I can't search on the encrypted data as I can't recreate the value that is stored in the database because the IV is stored as part of the data. Therefore the only way I can see to efficiently search is to create another hashed version of the data. I know that this will work, will be quick to implement and will be efficient, I'm just concerned that it would be less secure. I'll edit some pseudocode into the question if it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you want to be able to quickly test if some data is stored in the encrypted database, without having to decrypt the database.

Now, if *you* can search this database without decrypting (without the key) then so can an attacker search the database without the key. So, yes in general this is less secure.

Comment: Thanks. When you put it like that it seems quite obvious. Are there any general ways to mitigate this or otherwise get around the problem?

Comment: If all the data is encrypted with the same key, it is (depending on the encryption scheme) safe to encrypt the search-index with that key as well. Then with the key you can decrypt the search-index, and thus search efficiently, but an attacker can not (needs the key). A not general solution: you could also decide that the search-index does not contain secret material and so not decrypt it. Is that secure? Maybe, define secure ;)